# Matrix in GMP library (in C)

Tags: c, matrix, gmp

I am trying to define a matrix in gmp but I am getting error reports.
This is a slightly simplified version of my program:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <gmp.h>

mpz_t matrix[2][2];
mpz_init(matrix[0][0]), mpz_init(matrix[0][1]);
mpz_init(matrix[1][0]), mpz_init(matrix[1][1]);
mpz_set(matrix[0][0],1), mpz_set(matrix[0][1],2);
mpz_set(matrix[1][0],3), mpz_set(matrix[1][1],5);
```

and then my other programs etc but they error function is saying:

```
matdet.c:8:16: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘[’ token
```

So my question is, how do I define a matrix in gmp, 
Any help would be great!

Comment: Uh, you're trying to put method calls outside of a function?

Comment: I am quite new to C so that might have been my problem. I wrote two functions and want to use this matrix in my function, should I put it in main or in my functions. Thanks for the reply

Answer (score 1):

You should put those function calls into your main method. In C, it is not possible to do method calls outside of a method.